# Cannot use “Save As” to an FTP network location in Chrome

Tags: windows, ftp, android

I am using [WiFi FTP (WiFi File Transfer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nalic.app.wifishare&hl=en)—an Android app—to create a password protected FTP server. I am now able to map this as a network location in Windows 8.1. I can drop files in phone now over Wi-Fi.

However say if I open a Chrome and save the web page as PDF and try to give the destination (in “Save As” dialog) as a folder in a mapped network location which is my phone, it says I cannot save in this location.

I tried this with password-less FTP too, but the same thing happens. It does work by copy/cut pasting in Windows Explorer but not through the save as dialog. Is it related to the permissions of the program owning the “Save As” dialog?

Comment: Exact error message? Screenshot?

Comment: The API used by most apps (actually I never found any that doesn't) for reading and writing files doesn't recognize FTP (or MTP for that matter). File opened are actually downloaded or copied to temporary folder behind the screen

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo ok so do you mean its not the FTP by WiFi FTP on Android is a problem. In general too we cannot save file directly to FTP from doc editing or similar apps. Is it like that?

Comment: Yes, whether the FTP is hosted on Android or Windows Server made no difference. On the other hand, Windows apps can write directly into SMB server, so you might want to lookup various Samba implementation in Android

Comment: Actually I tried Samba first. I tried copy pasting files from ES Explorer and my PC. It was damn slow. Later I learned ES Explorer uses Samba internally. Is it like Samba is slow or ES Explorer's implementation of Samba is slow?

Comment: SMB should be fast enough since it's even possible for me to play games over 200MB through it on laptop.

Comment: now it seems that getting samba work on windows and android is not that easy...Windows is hard wired to communicate with Samba only on default port 445 and Without root we cannot make android run Samba on port < 1024. Thats what [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/using-smb-server-without-root-access) thread says. Havent tried this though.